# new item is not getting added in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

i am scanning devices from a bluetooth and getting their data from their advertisement,so one of the device gives the data of other devices which is not in ranged from the mobile device,so i specifically filter the data of that device which i wanted to show in recycler view in automatically updating the rssi values.
let's say,
a device A which gives the data of 3 devices B,C,D containing their rssi values continuously,so what i want to show the list of device B,C,D with their rssi values which is changing continuously.

What i have done  until now is scan that device "A",and extract the data of B and shown in recyclerview,but when another device i.e C's data comes in the old device i.e B got vanished and so on.
what i want is continuously changing data of B,C,D.

Adapter Class:-

```
public class ReapeaterDeviceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReapeaterDeviceAdapter.CryptoViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<RepeaterModel> data = new ArrayList<>();;
    private Context mCtx;

    public class CryptoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView mName, mPrice;

        public CryptoViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            mPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
        }
    }

    public ReapeaterDeviceAdapter(Context ctx,ArrayList<RepeaterModel> data) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public CryptoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.repeater_dev_data,parent, false);
        return new CryptoViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CryptoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        System.out.println("onBinder");
        holder.mName.setText(data.get(position).macdev);
        holder.mPrice.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).rssi));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CryptoViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {

        if (payloads.isEmpty()) {
            //System.out.println("onbinder");

            super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
        } else {
            Bundle o = (Bundle) payloads.get(0);
            //System.out.println("in keyset");

            for (String key : o.keySet()) {
                if (key.equals("price")) {
                    holder.mName.setText(data.get(position).macdev);
                    holder.mPrice.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).rssi));
                    //holder.mPrice.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    //this.notifyItemChanged(position);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<RepeaterModel> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<RepeaterModel> newData) {

        MyDiffUtilCallBack diffCallBack = new MyDiffUtilCallBack(newData, this.data);
        DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallBack);

        //this.setData(newData);
       // this.data=newData;
        this.data.clear();
       // this.data = newData;
       this.data.addAll(newData);
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);

        //this.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, this.getItemCount());
        //this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //System.out.println("Here");
    }


}
```

Model Class:-

```
    public String macdev;
    public int rssi ;
    public int imageid;

    public RepeaterModel(String macdev, int rssi, int imageid) {
        this.macdev = macdev;
        this.rssi = rssi;
        this.imageid = imageid;
    }

    public String getMacdev() {
        return macdev;
    }

    public void setMacdev(String macdev) {
        this.macdev = macdev;
    }

    public int getRssi() {
        return rssi;
    }

    public void setRssi(int rssi) {
        this.rssi = rssi;
    }

    public int getImageid() {
        return imageid;
    }

    public void setImageid(int imageid) {
        this.imageid = imageid;
    }





    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        System.out.println("in equals");
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof RepeaterModel)) return false;
        RepeaterModel that = (RepeaterModel) o;
        return getRssi() == that.getRssi() &&
                getImageid() == that.getImageid() &&
                getMacdev().equals(that.getMacdev());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getMacdev(), getRssi(), getImageid());
    }

   /*@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = Integer.valueOf(rssi);
       // result = result + (imageid != 0 ? imageid.hashCode() : 0);
        result = result + rssi.hashCode();
        System.out.println("hash");
        return result;
    }*/
}
```

Diffutilcallback :-

````
    ArrayList<RepeaterModel> newList;
    ArrayList<RepeaterModel> oldList;

    public MyDiffUtilCallBack(ArrayList<RepeaterModel> newList, ArrayList<RepeaterModel> oldList) {
        this.newList = newList;
        this.oldList = oldList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOldListSize() {
        return oldList != null ? oldList.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNewListSize() {
        return newList != null ? newList.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {

        if(newList.get(newItemPosition).getMacdev().equals(oldList.get(oldItemPosition).getMacdev()))
        {
           // Log.d("itemsame","in same");
            return true;
        }
        else {
           // Log.d("itemsame", "not same");
        }
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition)
    {
        //System.out.println("in content same");

        final RepeaterModel oldRepeater = oldList.get(oldItemPosition);
        final RepeaterModel newRepeater = newList.get(newItemPosition);

        if(oldRepeater.getRssi()!=(newRepeater.getRssi()))
        {
            //Log.d("item contenets","content different");
            return false;
        }
        //Log.d("item contenets","content same");
        return true;

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getChangePayload(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {

        RepeaterModel newModel = newList.get(newItemPosition);
        RepeaterModel oldModel = oldList.get(oldItemPosition);
        //System.out.println("getchange");

        Bundle diff = new Bundle();
        //if (newModel.getMacdev().equals(oldModel.getMacdev()))
        //{
            //System.out.println("getchange");

            if (newModel.getRssi()!=(oldModel.getRssi())) {
                diff.putInt("price", newModel.getRssi());
            }
                if (diff.size() == 0) {
                    return null;
                }


       // }
        return diff;
        //return super.getChangePayload(oldItemPosition, newItemPosition);
    }
}```



Activity Class:-

public class RepeaterAdvertise extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private static BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    private static boolean mScanning;
    private static Handler mHandler;
    private static final long SCAN_TIMEOUT = 20000;
    public DevData data;
    public Button cc;
    //List<BluetoothDevice> mBluetoothDevice;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ReapeaterDeviceAdapter reapeaterDeviceAdapter;
    ArrayList<RepeaterModel> modelArrayList;// = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_repeater_advertise);

        modelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.devdata);
        //dummyData();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        reapeaterDeviceAdapter = new ReapeaterDeviceAdapter(RepeaterAdvertise.this, modelArrayList);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(reapeaterDeviceAdapter);


        mHandler = new Handler();
        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        data = (DevData) intent.getSerializableExtra(SINGLE_DEV_DATA);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
       scanLeDevice(false,data.getMac_address());

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        scanLeDevice(true,data.getMac_address());

    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable,String mac) {
        if (enable) { // enable set to start scanning
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.

            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(mScanning) {
                        mScanning = false;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            //noinspection deprecation
                            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                        } else {
                            mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
                        }
                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    }
                }
            }, SCAN_TIMEOUT);

            mScanning = true;
            UUID[] motorServiceArray = {PSoCBleRobotService.getMotorServiceUUID()};
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                //noinspection deprecation
                mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(motorServiceArray, mLeScanCallback);
            } else { // New BLE scanning introduced in LOLLIPOP
                ScanSettings settings;
                List<ScanFilter> filters;
                mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
                settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                        .build();
                filters = new ArrayList<>();
                //ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(PUuid).build();
                //ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setManufacturerData(89,new byte[] {}).build();
                ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress(mac).build();
                filters.add(filter);
                if(mLEScanner==null)
                {
                    mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
                }
                mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);


            }
        } else { // enable set to stop scanning
            if(mScanning) {
                mScanning = false;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                    //noinspection deprecation
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                } else {
                    mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
                }
            }
        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
    private final BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    byte[] haha = scanRecord;

                   /* if(!mBluetoothDevice.contains(device))
                    {
                        //only add new devices

                        mBluetoothDevice.add(device);
                        mBleName.add(device.getName());
                        mBleArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Update the list on the screen
                    }*/

                }
            });
        }
    };
    public static String SbytesToHex(SparseArray<byte[]> bytes) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] dd = bytes.valueAt(0);

        for (byte b: dd)
        {
            builder.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        //System.out.println( dd.length);
        return builder.toString();

    }
    public final ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {

                ScanRecord scanRecord = result.getScanRecord();
              //  mBluetoothDevice.add(result.getDevice());
                SparseArray<byte[]> dataw = scanRecord.getManufacturerSpecificData();
            if (dataw.size() > 0) {
                //populate_devData(SbytesToHex(dataw));
                String data = SbytesToHex(dataw);
                ArrayList<RepeaterModel> repeaterModels= new ArrayList<>();
                int rssi = Integer.valueOf(data.substring(12, 14), 16) - 256;
                repeaterModels.add(new RepeaterModel(data.substring(0, 12), rssi, 1));

                insert(repeaterModels);



            } else if (false) {
                //alertDialog.dismiss();
                final Intent intent = new Intent(RepeaterAdvertise.this, ConfigurationView.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRAS_BLE_ADDRESS, data.getMac_address());
                intent.putExtra(EXTRAS_BLE_NAME, data.getName());
                intent.putExtra(SINGLE_DEV_DATA, data.getDev_data());
                scanLeDevice(false, data.getMac_address());
                //mconfig=false;
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

    };

    public void insert(ArrayList<RepeaterModel> rr)
    {
        modelArrayList.addAll(rr);
        reapeaterDeviceAdapter.setData(rr);

    }

}
````

Answer (score 1):

add this line in  insert function `reapeaterDeviceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
public void insert(ArrayList<RepeaterModel> rr){
    modelArrayList.addAll(rr);
    reapeaterDeviceAdapter.setData(rr);
    reapeaterDeviceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```